# Nginx responds to a server_name, while it shouldn't

Tags: nginx

I'm developing a new site, for which I have production and development versions. Production version is currently turned off and only development version is used for testing purposes. Both versions are located on the same IP address and have domain names `example.com` and `develop.example.com`.

I have 2 corresponding configuration files in my nginx `/etc/apps/sites-available`: `example.conf` and `develop.example.conf`, only `develop.example.conf` is enabled by a symlink in `sites-enabled`. SSL is enabled and all http connections are redirected to https.

**Still, for some reason `https://example.com` shows the development version of my site. Why?**

Here is `develop.example.conf`:

```
upstream django_develop {
    server unix:///tmp/develop.sock;
}

rewrite_log on;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name develop.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name develop.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media {
        alias /srv/develop/mysite/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/develop/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django_develop;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Strangely, `error.log` doesn't contain any rewrite entries.

Comment: Can we see the global nginx conf? Did you restart nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a catch-all server block, it'll default to the first one. You can read more about it here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: thanks for your help. You are right, all the requests to 443 seem to have been catched by develop server. I enabled ssl in `default.conf` and now it shows the "Welcome to nginx on Debian!" page for https, too.